# Proof of if $g$ is continuous and $g(x) = 0$ almost everywhere on the closed interval $[c,d]$, then $g(x) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose that $g$ is some continuous function on $[c,d]$. Now also suppose that $g(x) = 0$ almost everywhere on the closed interval $[c,d]$. We would like to prove that $g(x) = 0$,       $\forall x\in [c,d]$.

My proof is to do the following:

The set $X = \{x \in [c,d] \mid f(x) \neq 0\}$ is of measure zero. Now, suppose $X$ is not empty and contains at least some $x$. But, $X$ is the complement of a closed set and so $X$ is open. After this, I have no idea how to proceed, could someone please guide me along? thank you!

Comment: You're entirely right so far, and you're almost done.  Just one tiny step remains.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key fact to use here is that a set of full measure is dense. This follows immediately from noticing that its complement cannot contain any open intervals; do you see why?

Answer (score 1):

You said "$X$ is open".

Now just cite the fact that open sets have positive measure.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$ be given. By continuity, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - y| < \delta $ implies that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. For every $\delta > 0$, there exists $z \in N_{\delta}(x) \cap X^{c}$ since $m(X) = 0$. Therefore $|g(x)| = |g(x) - g(z)| < \epsilon$. Since $x \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$ are arbitrary, $g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [c,d]$.